# Is it possible to validate a GQL query in cloud datastore before submitting it? Any examples preferably using the Java lib

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

From the google code examples:

```
  public QueryResults<?> newQuery(String kind) {
    // [START newQuery]
    String gqlQuery = "select * from " + kind;
    Query<?> query = Query.newGqlQueryBuilder(gqlQuery).build();
    QueryResults<?> results = datastore.run(query);
    // Use results
    // [END newQuery]
    return results;
  }
```

Is it possible to validate the gqlQuery before officially running the query?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't. Your best option would be to test your queries with the `LocalDatastoreHelper` class, like it's done in [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/datastore/src/test/java/com/google/datastore/snippets/ConceptsTest.java). Check how it's set up and the `assertValidKey` and the GQL methods there.

Again, this is not actual validation of the query, but it seems like the best shot. Also, upon failures, the exception thrown would be `DatastoreException`, so, you can try and catch said exception in your code.